# Buffering videos leads to page loading slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, streaming, flowplayer

I am using `flowplayer` to play videos. I need to show first frame of every videos on my page. so I put the settings as autoPlay as false, and autoBuffering as true. So what happens is every videos (more than 10 videos) are buffering simultaneously and it leads the page loading very slow.

How can I overcome this?  Is there any way to stop the buffering after I got the first frame. I am using .net 3.5. Any inbuild feature in .net for this. videos will be only `.flv` and `.mp4`. The files will be from online also.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this forum post and the responses there](http://flowplayer.org/forum/2/10163) for some ideas of how to stop the buffering using javascript. You'll have to read through all the responses, because the common solution is mainly geared towards only ONE video on the page. But it may point you in the right direction.